# How can i know what l am reading with Java Sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I'm creating a Java Application wich need Client to communicate (Send & Recieve data) with other Clients.
I have made a simple Server Application to make Client communication easier.
To communicate, Server & Client use a Class that i have created named "Request". First, i was thinking that a Simple ObjectOutputStream/InputStream will ba able to send/recieve my Request Object and it is! But i have changed my plans:
Now, i serialize my Request Object as a byte array and i encrpyt it with Cipher. I already made the decryption & deserialisation method, but i dont know how to read byte array corresponding to the request. After having searched, i found that to know how many bytes i have to read, i have to send a int with the byte array lenth. I also found that a ByteArrayOuputStream/InputStream exists, is it adapted for me? And how to read/write the totality of a byte array ? 
Thanks you! Have a nice day!

Comment: So you've broken your design. So don't do that.

Comment: @EJP What do you mean? I just add encryption to my data, and to encrypt it, i have to make it as a byte array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the sending side, write the length of the byte array first and then the actual byte array:

```
OutputStream os = ...;
byte[] data = ...;
int dataLength = data.length;
os.write(dataLength >> 24);
os.write(dataLength >> 16);
os.write(dataLength >> 8);
os.write(dataLength);
os.write(data);
```

On the receiving side, read the first four bytes, reconstruct the data length and then read the appropriate number of bytes from the input stream:

```
InputStream is = ...;
byte[] buf = new byte[4];
is.read(buf);
int dataLength = (buf[0] << 24) + (buf[1] << 16) + (buf[2] << 8) + buf[3];
// read rest of data according to dataLength
```

Note:
The above code snippets don't include necessary sanity checks!

Comment: Thanks you! Works perfectly :D